# Error during the execution of a Send Mail Task In SSIS

Tags: email, ssis, smtp, send

I am trying to configure a Send Mail Task in SSIS. So far I have done this:
First I look for the smtp server in Outlook:

[image]

Then in SSIS I set the "Send Mail Task" with this value in the conection field.

[image]

But when I try to execute the task to send the message, I'm getting the error:

[Send Mail Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message:

```
"Error al enviar correo.  System.Net.WebException: No es posible conectar con el
 servidor remoto  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se produjo un error 
durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió 
adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la 
conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder 
10.158.122.33:25".
```

---

```
Something like "... It is not possible to connect with the remote server 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:...or maybe there is an
error in the connection because the connected host could not answer "
```

So, what can be wrong?

Regards.

Comment: Look for SMTP server log to discard authentication issues.

Comment: Alejandro podrí ser un poco más específico.... desconozco algunos temas técnicos en cuanto a este tipo de asuntos. Y si puede ser aclaratorio, debo tratar de enviar el mensaje desde la Intranet de la empresa.

Comment: Please note this is an english site. You are setting SSIS SMTP Connection Manager to use Windows authentication, does have the account that runs the package right permissions in Microsoft Exhange Server?